# Pointer of substring from pointer of string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm quite new to C and struggle with the following.

> Consider a string (pointer to an array of characters), containing an arbitrary amount of unsigned bytes, in our case, let it be `programming`. Write a function, which returns a pointer to a **new** location in memory (but not allocated with `malloc`), containing the substring of arbitrary but fixed size, at an arbitrary offset - in our case, let it be `gramm`.

I tried with the following:

```
unsigned char* newptr(unsigned char* p, int offset, int size) {
    unsigned char r[size];
    memcpy(r, p + offset, size + 1);
    return r;
}
```

but it errors with `Segmentation fault`. Otherwise

```
unsigned char* newptr = oldptr + offset;
```

works but it doesn't solve the problem with the fixed size - I don't want the rest of chars belonging to the pointer.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question was asked before, I just couldn't find anything of help.

Comment: Whoever told you a pointer is a string in C is fundamentally wrong. A C-string is an array of `char`. And an array is not a pointer. The task is also not clear. There are ways, but not using using variables which go out of existence when leaving their scope. That's what you are doing, btw.

Comment: `return r;` will not work, because the local variable `r` goes out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The problem is not going out of scope. That's also true for a local `static` variable. The problem is it also "goes out of life".

Comment: You can not return pointer to local variable from function, when function returns all local variables become invalid, that is why you get an error.

Comment: So how should I start then? I never worked with pointers before, so I would be glad I someone could outline the way into the right direction. :-)

Comment: In your task it is written that memory can not be allocated with malloc. But memory must be allocated somehow. There are several workarounds to do it, (global buffer, local static buffer, using allocation functions other then malloc, using existing memory of p variable) but it is not clear what of this workaround is ok for your task...

Comment: *"returns a pointer to a new location in memory (but not allocated with malloc)"* That is the crux of the problem, and how you're supposed to solve it must have been discussed in class. So you need to talk to some of the other students, or see one of the teacher's assistants.

Comment: @Sandro Oh, I forgot to mention it, as it wasn't in the scope of the text - everything is OK, as long as it is stack not heap.

Comment: @J.DoeNewmann That can only be done if the caller provides the buffer.

Comment: If this is indeed the original text, I don't see how students can learn _really useful C stuff_ from this problem.  "_pointer to a **new** location in memory_" does it mean that it points to [`operator new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/)  (and therefore a confusion between _C_ / _C++_)?

Comment: @CristiFati I agree, it's confusing to the end. Other students also don't know how to exactly tackle this "assignment".

Comment: :) So, we have a _not well formed_ question. You posted it here, got your answer, but not sure how much you learned from that (and it would be teacher's job to make sure you learn). Anyway from my PoV this is the perfect example for a lousy teacher (not sure if (s)he isn't also searching for answers to this very question here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible solutions, all them are non-optimal:

**Using global buffer** (using global variable is bad practice and if you call the function again it rewrites the buffer, buffer has fixed size and it must be larger then your size):

```
unsigned char r[100000];

unsigned char* newptr(unsigned char* p, int offset, int size) {
    memcpy(r, p + offset, size);
    r[size] = '\0';
    return r;
 }
```

**Using static local buffer** (has mostly the same problems as solution with global buffer):

```
unsigned char* newptr(unsigned char* p, int offset, int size) {
    static unsigned char r[100000];        
    memcpy(r, p + offset, size);
    r[size] = '\0';
    return r;
}
```

**Using memory of input** variable as buffer (the problem is then *p changes  after the function call)

```
unsigned char* newptr(unsigned char* p, int offset, int size) {
    p[offset + size] = '\0';
    return p + offset;
}
```

**Passing allocated buffer** into function:

```
unsigned char* newptr(unsigned char* p, int offset, int size, unsigned int* r) {
    memcpy(r, p + offset, size);
    r[size] = '\0';
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot!